# NPM run watch errors

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-start

Do anyone have idea what i have to do here?

```
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
```

I tested npm, runs version 3.5.2., but i can't use anything from npm.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have proper package.json file, that's why, you cannot run this command. You can create this file manually, or (better), run

```
npm init
```

to create this file. After this, you should install all your npm packages, using

```
npm install.
```

You can add this packages to package.json, or install them separately, using

```
npm i ... package name --save.
```

After this, you can run npm run start, but only when you predefined this inside "scripts" section in your package.json and define, what this scripts should do.